# Error when setting up WSo2 API Manager with MySQL

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have setup the CarbonDB to use the MySQL, and changed the identity.xml to use the Carbon db.

But when we run the -Dsetup we receive this error

```
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\soft\wso2am-2.1.0\bin\..\dbscripts\identity\mysql.sql (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.persistence.IdentityDBInitializer.executeSQLScript(IdentityDBInitializer.java:235)
```

is this expected? Is there any workaround?

Thanks,

Comment: You don't need to change anything on identity.xml file. You have to change the master-datasource.xml file only.

Comment: Hello @AbimaranKugathasan, I am not changing anything on it, when running the start with -Dsetup, it tries to execute this sql that doesn't exist. I was able to fix that by renaming the folder /dbscripts/apimgt to /dbscripts/identity.

Comment: I don't think it's correct. This should work OOTB. We use this feature on daily basis without any problems.

Comment: I agree with you, but for me it is not working when using mysql, I have not tried with other db engines. After the workaround it is working fine. Thanks